# Adding a value to a specific key whenever a certain object value is encountered

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with multiple tabs containing the names and info (e.g. ID, birthyear, committees) of different students in a school. Each tab has exactly the same format and contains the names of students that joined that particular committee. I have already managed to extract the information from each tab into a single array using Google Apps Script.

This array consists of multiple sub-arrays, with each sub-array representing 1 student.

e.g.

```
[[STUDENT 1, F1023****,PUBLICITY, 12/01/1901],[STUDENT 2, F2323****, TICKETING,  12/01/1921]]
```

I then passed the array into a function to create an array of multiple objects for each student in the array by iterating through the array above with this function:

```
function createPlayer(
      name,
      idNumber,
      committee,
      DOB
    ) {
      this.Name = name;
      this.ID= idNumber;
      this.Committee = committee;
      this.Birthday= DOB;
    }
```

This then creates an array of objects, where each object represents 1 student.

The problem now is that, each student may join different committees, and hence my array will consist of different objects with the same student, but with different values for the committee property.
e.g.

```
[{Name = 'STUDENT 1',
 ID = 'F301*****',
 Committee = 'PUBLICITY',
 Birthday = 21/09/1024
},

{Name = 'STUDENT 1',
 ID = 'F301*****',
 Committee = 'TICKETING',
 Birthday = 21/09/1024
},

{Name = 'STUDENT 2',
 ID = 'G301*****',
 Committee = 'MARKETING',
 Birthday = 21/09/1234
},
..
]
```

I want to be able to list down all the committees the student joined into the committee property in a single object.

e.g.

```
[
{Name = 'STUDENT 1',
 ID = 'F301*****',
 Committee = 'PUBLICITY, TICKETING',
 Birthday = 21/09/1024
},

{Name = 'STUDENT 2',
 ID = 'F301*****',
 Committee = 'PUBLICITY, MARKETING',
 Birthday = 21/09/1234
}
]
```

I know that it would be easier to simply reformat my data and and use Google Sheets formulas to extract the committees each student is in into a single cell before creating the objects, but ideally I'd like to be able to achieve this using GAS purely. I also have not been able to figure out the logic to achieve this so apologies for that. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That sounds like a design problem.  We answer code questions not design questions.

Comment: Create a hasmap using `Map` or `object` using ID as key. Then you can iterate  and do the needful